# stop clang -MM stripping path for object files

Tags: gcc, makefile, clang, clang++

I have a subdirectory with source in it. I would like `clang++ -I. -MM path/to/source.cpp` to give me the following output:

```
path/to/source.o: path/to/source.cpp path/to/source.h
```

Instead it gives me this:

```
source.o: path/to/source.cpp path/to/source.h
```

This seems like it would require me making Makefiles to list dependencies for every single source directory for my project?

Comment: I should mention, all above tagged compilers do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is possible (albeit not ideal) by using the -MT option as well.

`clang++ -I. -MM -MTpath/to/source.o path/to/source.cpp`

https://releases.llvm.org/6.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#id17